# Need to replace a string of special character in CSV through batch script

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have a CSV file in which the starting first 2 characters are special character. I need to remove them from the file. Need to write a batch script for this. Please suggest.

þÿLEAD_CO_MNE~BRANCH_CO_MNE~MIS_DATE~@ID~LIMIT_ID~PROCESS_DATE~

Comment: looks like UTF-16 bom...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like unicode bom chars sequense. And you need to convert it to plain text.Open your file with notepad go to file->save and in 'encoding' choose `ANSI`.
Not sure if WinXP has this option.

Comment: For the less geeky of us, bom = Byte Order Mark.  It specifies how a text file is encoded.

Comment: @npocmaka: Yes you are right it is a unicode bom chars sequence. The way you suggested cannot be done as such I would need a script to do this.

Comment: @Arpit - What means `cannot be done` ? Does not work or you need automated solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a script to handle this for you, use `set /P "variable=" <csvfile` to set a variable to the first line of the CSV file.  Use [string manipluation](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) to strip out the BOM, then a `for /f "skip=1"` to append the rest of the file.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "csvfile=test.csv"

<"%csvfile%" set /p "firstLine="

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
>fixed.csv echo(!firstLine:*ÿ=!
endlocal

for /f "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%I in ("%csvfile%") do (
    >>fixed.csv echo(%%I
)

>NUL move /y fixed.csv "%csvfile%"

echo Fixed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine `cmd` and `type` as follows:

For output as `ANSI` file without BOM

```
CHCP 1252 >NUL
start "" "%comspec%" /D /A /C type "path\file_with_BOM.csv">"path\file_-_BOM.csv"
```

For output as `UNICODE` file without BOM (here is a problem with endianity: Windows default to *Little-Endian* `UTF-16LE`, but your `þÿ` BOM looks like *Big-Endian* `UTF-16BE`)

```
CHCP 1252 >NUL
start "" "%comspec%" /D /U /C type "path\file_with_BOM.csv">"path\file_-_BOM.csv"
```

Code page 1252 is *West European Latin*, mine should be 1250 *East European Latin*; use `CHCP` with your locale-compliant proper page number